# Error trying to insert colored print in perl

Tags: perl

That's the code:

```
print color("red"), "INPUT>"; color("reset"); chomp($ip = <STDIN>);
```

In cmd, everything is fine 'til this line. The error is: *Undefined subroutine &main::color called at script2.pl line 7.*

Comment: No, the code is not fine. Replace the first semi-colon with a comma. `print color("red"), "INPUT>", color("reset");`  Copy and paste the code rather than recreate it. Place each statement on a new line for easier reading.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`Term::ANSIColor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) module.

From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor#SYNOPSIS):

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
print color('bold blue');
print "This text is bold blue.\n";
print color('reset');
print "This text is normal.\n";
print colored("Yellow on magenta.", 'yellow on_magenta'), "\n";
print "This text is normal.\n";
print colored(['yellow on_magenta'], 'Yellow on magenta.', "\n");
print colored(['red on_bright_yellow'], 'Red on bright yellow.', "\n");
print colored(['bright_red on_black'], 'Bright red on black.', "\n");
print "\n";
```